# Break statement with jstl

Tags: java, jstl, break

Well I have this piece of code

```
if(blastIt[i].startsWith("Lambda")){
            break;
        } else {

            System.out.println(blastIt[i]);
        }
```

So I'm trying to put this code on jstl

```
<c:choose>

    <c:when test="${fn:startsWith(blastIt, 'Lambda')}">


    </c:when>

            <c:otherwise>
       <p><c:out value="${blastIt}"/></p>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

But he is just removing the Lambda word from the text and I need to stop printing when he find the word Lamdba

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're doing this logic in the view layer?

Comment: No there isn't any particular reason, I was going to try to put everything in some ArrayList or something like that and show in the view, but I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

Try this with temp found variable

```
<c:set var="found" value = "0"/>

<c:choose>

    <c:when test="${fn:startsWith(blastIt, 'Lambda')}">
       <c:set var="found" value = "1"/>    
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <c:if test="${found==0}">
           <p><c:out value="${blastIt}"/></p>
        </c:if>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Comment: Man this code only remove the word but i need to remove everything after lambda